# SendInput won't send mouse events to on screen keyboard in Win 10

Tags: sendinput, on-screen-keyboard

I am trying to use SendInput to convert touches from a touch sensor into standard mouse events. This works fine with several standard Windows apps. But when I send a LEFT_MOUSE_DOWN event while over the OSK, nothing happens. And yet when I click with a standard mouse on the OSK it works fine. It's my understanding that SendInput injects the events at the same level as the mouse driver, so I don't see why sending them via SendInput does not work with the OSK.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Running in Admin mode helped.

Comment: Thanks alot!
You made my day and saved me a lot of work.